# gdal_cal.py with subprocess in python

Tags: gdal-calc, subprocess

I tried to do raster calculation and save the file to a new raster with subprocess in Python:

```
subprocess.run(['python', 'gdal_calc.py', '-A', image1, '-B', 'MSL_TEMP.tif', '--outfile = DEMNAS_MSL.tif', '--calc = A - B' ])
```

and comes with this error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not
> DatasetReader

Would you please give me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It can be run with this code:

```
subprocess.run(['python', 'gdal_calc.py', '-A', input1, '-B', input3, '--outfile=demnas_msl.tif', '--calc=A - B' ])
```

with input1 and input3 are string of input images. However, the result came in returncode =2

```
CompletedProcess(args=['python', 'gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'DEMNAS_KARIMUNJAWA.tif', '-B', 'msl_temp.tif', '--outfile=demnas_msl.tif', '--calc=A - B'], returncode=2)
```